# symfony : how to get rid of ugly GET parameters

Tags: forms, url, symfony1, filtering

i'm using form filtering to filter data in the frontend.

The problem is that the URL is ugly

```
 http://............./players/game/?st_player_cv_filters[location_id]=1&st_player_cv_filters[plateforme_id]=3&st_player_cv_filters[level_id]=3&st_player_cv_filters[_csrf_token]=023c5c9fb5fc7e7b6ed60d6839c36f67
```

(form rendered with :

```
 <?php echo $form->renderFormTag(url_for("game_player", $game), array('method' => 'get')); ?>
<table><tr><th><label for="location_id"><?php echo __('Country'); ?></label></th><td><?php echo $form['location_id']; ?></td></tr>
```

**How to render this url in a better way please ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the framework/API itself is a good idea if it supports your needs. By the sound of your question, you can likely use the [Symfony routing API](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/routing) to faciliate a solution...

For example, this [**book chapter**](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/09-Links-and-the-Routing-System) covers it:

> How to configure the routing rules to
>   change the appearance of URLs

Futhermore it speaks about long querystrings that you mentioned:

> For instance, a traditional URL
>   contains the file path to a script and
>   some parameters necessary to complete
>   the request, as in this example:
>
> http://www.example.com/web/controller/article.php?id=123456&format_code=6532

and speaks about the associated problems:

> The unintelligibility of URLs makes
>   them disturbing wherever they appear,
>   and they dilute the impact of the
>   surrounding content

The chapter provides [**HOW IT WORKS: examples of how to change your URLs**](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/09-Links-and-the-Routing-System#chapter_09_sub_how_it_works) using configuration and programming.

You should be able to maintain bookmarkability through easier to read/less complex/more secure URLs.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes when I run into this problem I run a redirect from the receiving page for the form to itself using symfony's redirect method.

```
$this->redirect('.../formAction?'.http_build_query($get_vars));
```

OR

use the url_for() method and such as:

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('.../formAction?'.http_build_query($get_vars)); ?>">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option, you could use POST rather than GET. That would clean up the url significantly.

Comment: yeah, but with POST user can't bookmark the result of the filters results. And with POST i have trouble keeping the parameters through pages (doctrine pager)